# Definite integration of functions containing (1/r^2)

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

While solving physics problems where functions containing 1/r^2 are very common,
I realised that the **definite integral** of the function **1/r^2** yields the result as **1/(geometric mean of the limits)^2.**

Does this have any significance or any intuitive logic as to why this is happening or is it a mere coincidence?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_a^b\frac1{r^2}\mathrm{d}r=\left[-\frac1r\right]_a^b=\frac1a-\frac1b=\frac{b-a}{ab}=\frac{b-a}{(\sqrt{ab})^2}$$